# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined (line 11, file "Code") in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
    function doGet(e){
handleFunction(e);

}

function doPost(e){
handleFunction(e);

}



function handleFunction(request){



var name = request.parameter.name;

var number = request.parameter.number;
var ss =    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afoMQY/edd=0");



 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('South Clubhouse');
  var rowContent = sheet.appendRow([name,number]);
}
```

I tried running it through postman several times I doesn't work. The params aren't working. What should I do to make it work properly?

Comment: Your code did work for me when I tested it. Could you provide more information? Which line is causing this issue? Because the line "11" has nothing on it.

Answer (score 2):

doPost and doGet deals with payload in different ways.

```
function doGet(e){
  var data = e.parameter;
  handleFunction(data);
}

function doPost(e){
  var data = e.parameter.data
  handleFunction(data);
}

function handleFunction(data){
  var name = data.name;
  var number = data.number;
  var ss =   
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afoMQY/edd=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('South Clubhouse');
  sheet.appendRow([name,number]);
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative but I don't think that's correct.  But I could be wrong.