# GAS OAuth2 - Getting an Access Token from "FREEE" - TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined Service_.handleCallback @ Service.gs:378"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

**Goal:**

- To get an access token from the service called [FREEE](https://developer.freee.co.jp/docs/accounting/reference).

**Code:**

- I ran the `authCallback` function in the code below. This code is from [here](https://support.freee.co.jp/hc/ja/articles/115000145263-freee-API%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B).

```js
/*
***********************************************************************************
参照ライブラリ
title               |OAuth2
project_key  |1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF
***********************************************************************************
*/

//連携アプリ情報（Googleスプレッドシートサンプルファイル）
var APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// 認証のエンドポイントとなるダイアログ
function alertAuth() {
  var service = getService();
  var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplate('認証. ');
  template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
  var page = template.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(page, "認証が必要です");
}

//freeeAPIのサービスを取得
function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('freee')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.secure.freee.co.jp/public_api/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.secure.freee.co.jp/public_api/token')
      .setClientId(APP_ID)
      .setClientSecret(SECRET)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
}

//認証コールバック(アクセストークンの取得)
function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  var access_token = service.getAccessToken();

  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('認証に成功しました。タブを閉じてください。');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('認証に失敗しました。タブを閉じてください。');
  }
}
```

**Error Message**:
But I get this error message.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined

> Service_.handleCallback   @ Service.gs:378

Service.gs is [this](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/src/Service.js) . The code block including line 378 is below.

```
Service_.prototype.handleCallback = function(callbackRequest) {
  var code = callbackRequest.parameter.code;
  var error = callbackRequest.parameter.error;
  if (error) {
    if (error == 'access_denied') {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Error authorizing token: ' + error);
    }
  }
  validate_({
    'Client ID': this.clientId_,
    'Client Secret': this.clientSecret_,
    'Token URL': this.tokenUrl_
  });
  var payload = {
    code: code,
    client_id: this.clientId_,
    client_secret: this.clientSecret_,
    redirect_uri: this.getRedirectUri(),
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  };
  var token = this.fetchToken_(payload);
  this.saveToken_(token);
  return true;
};
```

**Comment:**

- I am stuck. Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this problem!! Thank you.

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580613/1841839

Comment: Can you explain your objective in more detail? Obtaining an access token" is very superficial. According to the documentation: `If you are trying to connect to a Google API from Apps Script you might not need to use this library at all. Apps Script has a number of easy-to-use, built-in services, as well as a variety of advanced services that wrap existing Google REST APIs.` So I wonder, what is your scenario and why is the traditional way of getting an access token in Apps Script not working for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the code. My final goal is running a script to get the access token from the website called FREEE (https://developer.freee.co.jp/docs/accounting/reference).

 To understand the mechanism, I tried to run the code published from google's official page (https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2). But it seems like I should put the FREE's code directly. I updated the code. 

Sorry for the confusion.  And yes, using the Google Script Editor, I don't have to write the code to get access.